# iCloud sync of my note deleted some parts by itself

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, data-synchronization, notes.app

I am using Notes (the stock app) on my iPhone and on my Mac, synced throught iCloud. I have a note where I put some brainstorming in. Sometimes I add stuff on my Mac, and sometimes I add to it on my iPhone.

However, when I opened Notes on my Mac, it literally deleted a paragraph (leaving only the first letters) after about two seconds opening the Notes.app (probably, after the iCloud sync). It's gone both on my Mac and on my iPhone. *I'm sure that I did not delete or write anything on that particular lost part*. It just merged incorrectly resulting in data loss. Worse, I can't find a way to recover the lost data. Why is this happening and how do I prevent it (keeping the same iCloud sync functionality and still using the same note)?

Comment: Did you see the solutions on [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/47189/88313)?  Do any of the answers help?

Comment: @fbara I haven't deleted the note, that question is about recovering a deleted note. In my case, the note is there, it's just iCloud sync wrote on top of some of its content.

Comment: Recovering a previous version of a note, a version prior to the accidental destruction of content may help to recover this lost content. [return] But the truth is that it isn't easy to revert a syncing mechanism when it is propagating corrupted information.

Comment: @danielAzuelos how do I recover the previous version? I could copy it from there and paste it to the newest version back. (not the best practice, but would at least revert the data loss)

Comment: Read the question suggested by @fsb.