# I accidentally deleted a note in iCloud

Tags: icloud, restore, notes.app

I deleted a note from iCloud in my iPhone, I thought that it was only an extra copy of the actual note, so I deleted it. I tried to find ways to recover the note but it seemed impossible. I was wondering if it is possible for the deleted iCloud note to be recovered in my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Right after you accidentally delete the note, give your iPhone a quick shake and it will prompt a message asking you if you want to undo the last action.

[Here is some more information about this feature](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3717178). (It also mentions that you can restore the OS from a backup - assuming you've synced recently)

Also, there is already [another Post that addresses this issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47189/can-i-recover-a-deleted-icloud-note). You might want to look into that as well.