# Retrieving an accidently deleted notes folder well after 30 days

Tags: iphone, recovery, notes.app

Back in April, I believe I essentially accidentally deleted notes at a concert. I done this through the Manage Storage section (not through the actual Notes app), and when I went into the Notes app the next day to try and retrieve them, not only was there nothing in my recently deleted, but the entire "On My iPhone" notes folder had been completely removed without a trace.

I've tried to retrieve them through several apps such as FoneLab, iMyFone and PhoneRescue to no avail. I was wondering if I've left it too late and/or the manner in which I deleted them - through the Manage Storage section and also apparently as an entire folder, not as individual notes - means they are permanently gone?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you're not able to retrieve them with what you've tried already, they're probably gone.

Comment: Also see (amongst many) https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/47189/237687

Comment: Were you able to solve this ? I have a similar issue

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't got backups of your device, it is very unlikely that you'll be able to retrieve these notes after 8 months. If you've left the device on the shelf, powered off for those 8 months, there's a slim chance - but if you have used the device, it is extremely unlikely.

You'll have to take the iPhone to a lab that does recovery from the flash storage devices on iPhones. It will be costly, and there's really only a very, very slim small chance that your notes can be found again.